# KSOAP2-ANDROID - calling webservice method in a thread

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am implementing a web service call from within a thread in android, the first call goes successfully but every subsequent call returns this error every time.

```
    02-27 13:00:04.735: W/System.err(2681): java.net.ConnectException: 192.168.9.79/192.168.9.79:8080 - Network is unreachable
```

Please what am I supposed to do?

Comment: whats ur minsdkversion?? and which ksoap2-android...jar file you are using??

Comment: are you closing the previous connection?

Comment: Thanks guys, it was me that was the problem, seems android has a way of working threads like Handlers and AsyncTask and other stuff of their ilk. Put the offending code in an handler and now it works perfectly.